# Can I use custom Graph API actions to embed actions within facebook posts to perform something on my website?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

Can I use a custom graph api action to perform some additional actions on my website, for e.g. **an action to cast a vote (via ajax) on the site's content from within facebook posts**.

***Edited...***

I mean to say in normal facebook posts we have like, share & comment actions at the bottom. So can we put our own custom actions there that can perform something on the actual site.

Comment: Please re-phrase, this is hard to understand what you are saying. Open Graph Actions are from your site to Facebook Timeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into Action Links, you should be able to make a server call from Facebook to your site back to Facebook with the specified action - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actionlinks/

[image: Before]

[image: After]